# making a python function input a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding for a function and want to turn this input,

```
[], [], ["pepperoni", "pepperoni"], wings=[10, 20], drinks=["small"]
```

in a function cost_calculator

The problem is it is not letting me take it since there is the word wings and drinks in it. Trying to convert it into a list gives me wrong syntax. I also cannot take out the words wings and drinks form the input.  my code:

```
def cost_calculator(x):
    cost=0
    drinks={"small":2.00,"medium":3.00,"large":3.50,"tub":3.75}
    wings={10:5.00,20:9.00,40:17.50,100:48.00}
    toppings={"pepperoni":1.00,"mushroom":0.50,"olive":0.50,"anchovy":2.00, "ham":1.50}
 pizza={[]:13.00}
 for i in x:
        if i in pizza:
            cost=cost+pizza[i]
        elif i in toppings:
            cost=cost+toppings[i]
        elif i in drinks:
            cost=cost+drinks[i]
        elif i in wings:
            cost=cost+wings[i]
        else:
            break
  return cost
```

when inputing

```
cost_calculator([], [], ["pepperoni", "pepperoni"], wings=[10, 20], drinks=["small"])
```

it gives me

```
cost_calculator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wings'
```

i need to use [] for showing the value of a pizza which should make

```
cost=cost+13.00
```

how can i overcome this

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Hi, please copy&paste the code from the screenshot into your question.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not totally sure what the arguments to the function are, but if you want to use keyword args, use the `**` syntax:</strike>

So, I think I understand what the args can be (in this order):

- Any number of `[]`, each representing one pizza
- One list of toppings (apparently this is optional)
- Optional named lists (wings, drinks)

So we can use [variable number of args](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [keyword args](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
# Tuple of var args and a dictionary of keyword args
def cost_calculator(*args, **kwargs):
    drinks = {"small": 2.00, "medium": 3.00, "large": 3.50, "tub": 3.75}
    wings = {10: 5.00, 20: 9.00, 40: 17.50, 100: 48.00}
    toppings = {"pepperoni": 1.00, "mushroom": 0.50, "olive": 0.50, "anchovy": 2.00, "ham": 1.50}

    cost = 0
    coupon_value = 0.0

    # args is a tuple of unnamed parameters
    for a in args:
        # [] has 0 length so it's a pizza
        if 0 == len(a):
            cost += 13.00
        # Otherwise it must be toppings
        else:
            cost += sum([toppings[x] for x in a if x in toppings])

    # Step through the keyword args
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        if key == "drinks":
            cost += sum([drinks[x] for x in value if x in drinks])
        elif key == "wings":
            cost += sum([wings[x] for x in value if x in wings])
        elif key == "coupon":
            coupon_value = value
        else:
            break
    return cost * (1.0 - coupon_value)

c = cost_calculator([], [], ["pepperoni", "pepperoni"], wings=[10,10], drinks=["small"], coupon=0.1)
print(c)
```

Comment: the thing is that i have to use an empty set to signify pizza and toppings should just be in the set so the input should be something like this:               [],[], ["pepperoni","olives"], wings=[20],drinks=["tub"]      where [] should tell to add 13 to the cost while for the others you will have to iterate it through the list.

Comment: this works with multiple amount of items but when you use cost_calculator([])     it outputs zero

Comment: @AnveshSunkara Updated again. In the future you should try to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: what if there was another input coupon where the input is [],[], ["pepperoni","olives"], wings=[20],drinks=["tub"] ,coupon =0.1....then the last thing should be s=1-coupon and cost = cost * s but this doesn't iterate over floats.

Comment: @AnveshSunkara Updated for coupon.

Comment: yeah but this doesn't seem to work when the input is just a tub sized drink and a coupon of 0.1